# Swippable behavior of tabs not working when using NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-tabs, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to learn Material Design, I am trying to make a layout like current layout of Whatsapp home screen

[image]

It all works fine i had set up my tabs and also able to make swipe layout in tabs, now when i tried to make AppBarLayout exit the screen along with content when scroll, so that my content gets some more height while scrolling and my toolbar hide while scrolling. For that,

I had included `NestedScrollView` as parent of my `content_main` layout, And i included that `content_main` inside my `activity_main` but **due to use of nested scroll view the swipe behavior of tabs are gone.**

Currently its working like [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/designlibrary/scrolling2_1.mp4) but tabs are not swippable now, tabs are working properly when i clicked them.

What can be the issue?

### content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tb_activity_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:id="@+id/tabs_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:id="@+id/content_main"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_activity_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync_noanim" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: You'll need to include your code.  A similar setup certainly works for the [cheesesquare sample app](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Comment: yes i have already seen chhesefactory example but problem is i can not get reason why its happening with NestedScrollVIew i am editing my question please check it out @ianhanniballake